# Как растянуть весь контент на всю высоту экрана?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы секция автоматически подбирала высоту и заполняла все свободное место? Т.е. чтобы белой полосы не оставалось снизу?

Есть ли варианты решить это на CSS? Если нет, то как это решить на JS?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

section {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

footer {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header></header>
  <section></section>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

P.S. Мои наброски на JS

```js
var header = document.querySelector('header');
var footer = document.querySelector('footer');
headerH = parseInt(getComputedStyle(header).height);
footerH = parseInt(getComputedStyle(footer).height);
var screenHeight = parseInt(document.body.clientHeight);
var pageSection = document.querySelector('section');
pageSection.style.height = screenHeight - headerH - footerH + 'px';
```

Но тут, что-то не так высчитывается, вероятно потому-что `document.body.clientHeight` это высота `body`, а не высота окна браузера

Comment: Какой элемент должен быть на всю высотку страницы? Например, `.wrapper` на всю высоту.

Comment: Никакой элемент не должен быть на всю высоту. Нужно что бы вся страницы была на всю высоту. Для этого нужно чтобы section элемент автоматически подпирал высоту что бы заполнять пространство до конца страницы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот такое нужно ?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

section {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: blue;
}

footer {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header></header>
  <section></section>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body,
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

section {
  /* 100% - (header height + footer height ) */
  height: calc(100% - (50px + 300px));
  background-color: blue;
}

footer {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header></header>
  <section></section>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Comment: а мне понравился больше ваш ответ. Вопрос хоть и простой, но у вас решение выглядит более профессионально.